# Can't do delete folder with the tag present in the reparse buffer point is invalid

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive, reparse-points

There are two folders I have that are both subfolders in two seperate directories. I needed to delete both of their parent directories and what I found was that everything except those two folders were deleted. When I try to delete them, I keep getting an error saying "the tag present in the reparse buffer point is invalid". (In the OneDrive desktop if that helps)

I have tried a number of ways to get past this. I tried using the `rm -force` command in powershell (kept saying doesn't have access to the cloud file), the `del` command in command prompt, running chkdsk (also, ever since this happened my PC has been running chkdsk on startup every time), booting up in safe mode, and deleting them in OneDrive live to see if my desktop would sync that way (onedrive live successfully deleted them, but they aren't getting deleted on  my PC).

Another strange thing is that the file names are the same and keep changing despite having nothing to do with each other. They are both named `pIFgTVfE` but weren't originally called that, and I couldn't find any pattern to when they both simultaneously change-- they just do.

I am really confused about this and am worried that something might be wrong with my SSD.

Comment: Check out [Windows Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html) [freeware version is sufficient] which has a reparse point 'fixer'.

Comment: @Tetsujin For some reason, windows repair couldn't find any problems with reparse points in those folders

Comment: Interesting, if irritating :\ Did you do the full 'pre-amble'… clean, safe boot etc that it recommends? [I don't really think it would make any practical difference for reparse points, but it's worth following each of its panels exactly as it says, just in case] It might also be worth pushing through the rest of the tests/fixes, though that can take some time to do all of it. It's not any kind of 'go faster' tool, it's just a 'make everything work as it should' so it will never break anything.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah I did that, but it still didn't work. However, when I ran the full scan, it finally let me delete the files. I have no idea why the error want identified as a reparse point error, but hey, it got fixed somehow. Also it stopped checking the disk on startup as well.

Comment: Glad you got it - even if we're not sure quite how ;) Keep that tool around, it's darned useful on occasion. [I have no affiliation, merely a satisfied customer]

Comment: The Windows Repair -utility is useless. All the background processes it left running keeps me shivers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot delete a folder that have the "The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid"](https://superuser.com/questions/1598874/cannot-delete-a-folder-that-have-the-the-tag-present-in-the-reparse-point-buffe)

Answer (score 1):

linking to my recent answer on a related question. It may help anyone who stumbles upon this issue and doesn't want a specific tool to solve the problem:
[Link to another Answer on SuperUser about this issue](https://superuser.com/a/1734952/942116)